# Correctly load level without modifying the original

Tags: object, static, copy, loading, xna-4.0

Currently, my game works like this :

```
public class TheGame: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public static Level CurrentLevel;
    private Level level1, level2, level3;


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        level1 = new Level(//param);
        level2 = new Level(//param);
        level3 = new Level(//param);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        If(something)
          LoadLevel(level1);

        currentLevel.Update(gameTime);
        //
    }

    LoadLevel(Level theLevel)
    {
        currentLevel = theLevel;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i modify the currentLevel with an Update(), that modifies Level1 too.

```
For example :
Level1 has a crate with position (100,200).
if currentLevel.Update() modifies the crate's position (120,200),
that modifies the crate's position in CurrentLevel AND the crate's position in Level1.
```

So when i reload Level1, the level is different from the original level1.

Is it because of Static ? because i have to clone Level1 ? Something else ? :s
Thx for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always loading the same variable, since you store `level1`, `level2` and `level3` as instance variables of your main Game class and assign them to currentLevel in an instance method. The static modifier has nothing to do with it.

Instead, you should reload the level each time or rebuild it from whatever data you have loaded. Another option is having a method which restores it to its original state, but this requires that everything in the level can be reverted to a known initial state. Usually, simply reloading assets or cloning them is easier.